# Attempting to load a datatable - Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle

I'm trying to connect & query an Oracle DB and load the results into a datatable but I keep getting the 'operation is not valid due to the current state of the object' error for the code below:

```
Using conn As New OracleConnection(oradb)

        Try

            cmd = New OracleCommand()
            da = New OracleDataAdapter(cmd)
            dteDTK = New DataTable()
            conn.Open()
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1"
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            da.Fill(dteDTK)

        Catch ex As OracleException

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString())

        Finally

            conn.Close()
            conn.Dispose()

        End Try

End Using
```

The error throws on the 'da.Fill(dteDTK)' command. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not assigning the Connection to the Command. I would imagine that you need to do this on OracleCommand:

```
cmd.Connection = conn
```

Otherwise, you are executing a SQL statement on a command that has no connection associated.

Comment: who had thought this answer help a person in 2022 :) :)